# When a membership is created by webform, is it possible to automatically have it set to auto-renew?

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm, stripe, auto-renew

We are using drupal 9, civi 5.58, and stripe 6.7.8-dev. The webform membership form we created works perfectly in creating the membership, but it will not set it to auto-renew. The membership type in civicrm is set to auto-renew.

Is it possible to do this in the webform configuration? Or is there a robust workaround that someone has discovered?

Comment: Just to be clear the auto-renew flag is a property of how someone _pays_ for their membership rather than the membership itself. If someone sets up a recurring payment for their membership there will be a corresponding recurring contribution in CiviCRM and the membership will show the auto-renew flag. So the answer is to ensure that the webform accepts recurring payments as shown in Pradeep's answer below.

Comment: What payment processor are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable RECURRING CONTRIBUTION in your webform settings under CiviCRM >> Contribution section.

[image]